# Dependend dropDown in JSF when i select Area dependend Region should come ,when i select Region depedent City should come and so on

Tags: jsf

When I click on Area in drop down internally "onAreaSelection" is called but after that "OnRegionSelecton" and other selection is also calling,and my region value is coming as per Area selection.

But when i am selecting Region, internally again "onAreaselection" ,"OnCitySelection" is calling but not "onRegionSelection" call happen.

```
<html:selectOneMenu tabindex="34" id="areaName" value="#{ContactInfoEdit.currentUser.areaName}"
                    styleClass="textEnterMode" valueChangeListener="#{ContactInfoEdit.onAreaSelection}"
                    onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <faces:selectItems id="selectAreaItem1" value="#{ContactInfoEdit.areaDropdown}"/>
</html:selectOneMenu>

<html:selectOneMenu tabindex="18" id="regionName" value="#{ContactInfoEdit.currentUser.regionName}"
                    styleClass="textEditMode" valueChangeListener="#{ContactInfoEdit.onRegionSelection}"
                    onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <faces:selectItems id="selectRegionItem1" value="#{ContactInfoEdit.regionDropdown}"/>
</html:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: `this.form.submit` is not useful for this, use ajax instead. See duplicate for kickoff example.

Comment: `this.form.submit` is pre 2005 html usage

Comment: @BalusC i am using old jsf...ajax is not supporting